# NCBI Blast API use QuickBLASTP program

Tags: python, blast, ncbi

I'm using NCBI Blast's web API. In their browser-based Blast search, they offer a program called QuickBLASTP which is immensely faster than the regular blastp. How can I use this program inside of their web API? On the documentation, it says that only blastp, blastn, tblastn, tblastx, and blastx were allowed, but I was wondering if there was a way to use the quicker protein blast instead.